# Re-installing Google Play Store

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, google-play-store

My Google Play store, as well as all of my apps, are messed up. Every one of them has an Android icon and an SD card emblem at the bottom right. I do not know how to get my Play Store back, and I can not use any apps.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Talking of "getting it back": Is it gone? Did you try to clear it's cache and, maybe, uninstall its updates? (it would auto-update again then)

Comment: I tried clearing its  cache and its not gone, just like all of my other apps it has an android with a picture of a SD card...

Comment: If all of your apps are affected, and you don't find a better solution, a last resort is always a *factory reset*, though this would also delete all your data (so make sure you have a good backup).